# Why didn't Indigo retain the negative effects of the star?

Tags: the-worst-witch

On *The Worst Witch*, Miss Hardbroom believes that using a wishing star to give magic to someone born without it will inevitably result in their going [drunk on the dark side](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DrunkOnTheDarkSide) until they renounce their powers, with less-biased individuals such as  Miss Cackle somewhat agreeing. The limited evidence seen in the show suggests that she is at least partly correct. For instance, Mildred's mother, normally mild and kind, progressed within months to turning people into statues for mere slights and *laughing evilly about permanently turning her daughter into clay*; after giving up her powers, she reverted to her usual personality. Indeed, Indigo herself seemed ready to try to vanish the entire academy mere hours after acquiring her powers.

However, after being revived by the potion, Indigo showed no signs of being evil, and little more than the recklessness she'd demonstrated before getting her powers. It's not like the potion was a cure for power-induced insanity—it rather seemed a cure for negative transformations: it dealt handily with other transfigurations, such as being turned to clay or a cake; conversely, basically no one thought it was safe for Ms. Hubble to keep her powers after using the potion.

So why did Indigo not show any of the negative effects of the wishing star after being revived?